# Difference between 'he is gone out' and 'he has gone out'?

Tags: vocabulary

I am confused between

> He is gone out

and

> He has gone out

Translation of both, the sentences mean the same. Can anyone explain which one should i use.

Comment: We don't normally say "He is gone out." in English. The helping verb is "have"/"has".

Comment: @Lorel C but the meaning of both are same. Then how would I know which one should I choose?

Comment: _He is gone out_ is archaic. You will find many examples of it in Early Modern English texts, such as the King James Bible. Anybody who uses it today is being deliberately archaic.

Comment: "He is gone" can mean that he is "out of his mind".

Comment: He is gone; he is come. I use them from time to time. I would call these a bit old-fashioned rather than "archaic".

Comment: @WeatherVane: or that he is heavily under the influence of mind-altering substances...

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: "he is gone" still gets regular use. A sort of specific holdover, I guess. Or a confusion due to it having the same contraction. It is also used specifically for people dying, of course.

Comment: @SamBC I didn't give any reason but intended that to be included: "lost his mind" could be a temporary or permanent issue, or even in a day-dream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"He **is** gone out" is not idiomatic English. It treats "gone out" as an adjective or other description of state. This is not usual.

"He **has** gone out" is normal present perfect construction. It is saying that, at some point in the past, he went out. Usually, this means he's not in at the moment, though it will occasionally be used when he's already come back - though "he has **been** out" is more usual, then.

Both contract naturally to "he's gone out", which may be a source of confusion.

If you want to use a descriptive present tense to describe his state, given that he's gone out, you use ***out*** as an adjective: "he **is** out", or contracted to "he's out".

---

n.b.: You will find "he is gone out" and similar constructions, using *is* instead of *have* for the present perfect, in older texts. It was once a normal thing, but hasn't been for some time.

Comment: "He has gone out" can also mean that he is not here right now.

Comment: @anouk: yes, quite frequently that's what it's used to mean. Even usually. It's literal meaning is that he went out. You wouldn't usually say it if he'd also come back (though sometimes you would).

Comment: Maybe emphasize that "has" is the regular auxiliary verb in any perfect-tense construction. "Has spoken", "has gone", "has written", "has had".